# JavaScript increment unary operator (++) on strings

Tags: javascript, specifications

I am on Chromium Version 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

According to the [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4), prefix increment operator is evaluated as follows:

[image: Prefix Increment Operator evaluation steps]

With this in mind, I cannot explain this result:

```
++'1';
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

when the following code works like a charm:

```
var x = '1'; 
++x;
> 2
```

As far as I understand, in both cases the first 3 bullet points of the second step are true, whereas for `++'1'` case the fourth bullet is also true (but why?) and for the `++x` case it is false, raising no error. Am I right?

PS: Firefox throws a `SyntaxError: invalid increment operand` instead of a `ReferenceError`

Comment: You get the same error if you do ++1, by the way

Comment: `PutValue('1', 2)` throws an error because it cannot assign to a string literal. You need a variable or some other kind of `Reference`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your `++` operator implicitly involves an **assignment**, and you can't assign a new value to a string constant. Note that

```
++2;
```

is also erroneous for the same reason.

Comment: …which presumably happens in `5. Call PutValue(expr, newValue)`?

Comment: Oh.. I missed that out. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

In my understanding, `++` is similar to `+= 1`.

So it will work for `++x` as it will be evaluated to `x+=1` or `x=x+1`, but `++'1'` is a string literal and does not has left hand side value to assign, hence it fails

Comment: You can even literally do `'1' = Number('1')+1` and will get the same error

Comment: Because left hand side value is not valid. you cannot have `'1'` as variable name

Comment: Oh.. I missed that out. Thanks for the answer!